# Specific user cannot see other users in Standard User Report

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting, sharing, sales-cloud, owd

**Scenario :**

- A User Adam of 'Regional' Role **creates** a User report for the User Bob of 'Country Head' Role (Role Hierarchy is 'Country Head' reports to 'Regional').
- Report has the **filter** as Login Date EQUALS 'LAST MONTH'
- Adam shares the Report Folder of 'View' access to 'Roles and Subordinates' of Regional.
- In the User Report, Adam can see all the Users in the report. However when Bob sees the report, he can only see his own record .. **Problem why can't Bob see all his Subordinate users?**

Other Considerations:

- Sharing Settings for User is Default Internal Access = Public Read Only & Default External Access = Private
- Adam & Bob have same Read & Edit FLS for all User fields
- Standard Report Visibility
- 'View All Users' Profile permission for Bob is enabled

Comment: Are you sure there is no additional filter on the report? Given the OWD on the User object is Public Read Only, all the user records should be visible to all internal users. Also, check if this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324873&type=1&mode=1) helps?

Comment: Report filter -> Last Login = All Time

Other permissions I used: 
- Standard Report Visibility ticked, 
- System Permissions -> "View All users", "Manage Internal Users". 

All still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some obscure reason, creating a **Custom Report Type** for User seemed to have solved the issue -> Bob is able to see all his subordinate records now as mentioned in this [blog](https://mywaysalesforce.wordpress.com/2021/01/04/report-on-user-for-non-system-admin-users/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is related to a record  control access the fact  that Bob can't see the records that Adam can see. To troubleshoot accesibility discrepancies **please check the Organization wide default** ( this is the basis of your sharing data model in your Org.). If the "OWD" is private for the object "User", this means that only record owners can see records related to that object. To grant access you should use other tools for accessibility ( like sharing rules, manual sharing,  role hierarchy, etc.) . In this scenario Adam and Bob has different "Roles" so they should see different records ( if the sharing data model for "User" is private).

You can use this documentation for further understanding of the control access to your records: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_data_access.htm

Let me know if this help you and good luck!

Comment: Yes, I've already stated in my question about the OWD "Sharing Settings for User is Default Internal Access = Public Read Only & Default External Access = Private"